# ¿Cómo hago esta validación

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify

Como hago esta misma validación del script si el campo esta vacío.. que diga campo vacío pero con vuetify en el template, yo hice una parecida de eliminar, pero solo era un aviso de si queria eliminar el registro, con condiciones no sé como hacerlo.
Esta es la función registrar:

```
const registrar=()=>{
        let nom=ref()
        dato.value.forEach((elem:any)=>{
            nom.value = elem.name
            if(nom.value == nombre.value){
                alert("Rol repetido..")
                limpiar()
                return
            }
        }) 
        if(nombre.value==""){
            alert("campo vacio..")
            return
        }
```

En Vuetify lo estaba haciendo así, aunq no me acepta que ponga nombre.value, mientras que en el script si me deja

```
<v-row>
            <v-col >
                
                <v-btn class="elevation-5 text-blue-grey-darken-4 bg-blue-grey-lighten-5 rounded-lg btn_mas" @click="registrar()">Añadir</v-btn>
                <h3 v-if="nombre.value === ''">Campo vacio..</h3>

            </v-col>
            
        </v-row>
```

Les agradezco sus soluciones de antemano..

Comment: Se entiende que existe una variable nombre que al parecer enumera unos roles pero luego en `registrar()` esta validando si esta vacío, y eso no tiene sentido. Al parecer esta mal implementada la lógica: Tendría que tener dos variables como estado,  una donde reciba el rol y otra donde estén lo roles estandar. Luego basta usar computed para hacer la operación de validación, según sea retornar el mensaje necesario para usarlo en el template con el v-if.